# No system resource manager for module: app in android studio 3.1

Tags: android-studio-3.1

No system resource manager for module: app in android studio 3.1
The problem when it android studio android 3.1 I have unfortunately entered into the finish inbuild library files after, it shows download or refreshes if u already downloaded, I used download after that this error is coming.

that filename activity.xml

Answer (score 12):

Let's try File > Sync project with Gradle .
In my case, it works well.

Comment: Worked for me. Many Thanks. After that, I also had to add "Base" to the Style in "styles.xml": <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Comment: This worked for me when dealing with different modules in the same app. 
The Gradle for each module sometimes needs a File>Sync project with Gradle.