# Don't have Resource manager in Android studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I don't have "Resource Manager" in my Android Studio.
Everything is working but the Resource Manager tab is missing and doesn't appear in the menu View > Tool window neither.

My version of Android Studio is Artic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No system resource manager for module: app in android studio 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685917/no-system-resource-manager-for-module-app-in-android-studio-3-1)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I find my own answer and maybe it could help someone so :
I had to add the "sync project with gradle files”.

1- Go to File > Settings in Appearance > Menu & Toolbars search for "sync project with gradle files”
2- In the list, select "Sync project with gradle files” (with the elephant icon) and then click on the OK button.
3- Restart few times and Resource Manager will appear :)

Answer (score 0):

File -> Repair IDE worked for me after following 3 steps in the repair steps which asked me to restart IDE and then View -> Tool Windows -> Resource Manager appeared.